# How can I check the checkbox based on the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check the checkbox based on the text in the next column. Here's how I did it, is there a more concise way?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fyscpxr/)

```
<table id="table1">
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Text 1</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Text 2</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Text 3</td></tr>
</table>

$(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    //this.checked = true;
    var strVal = $(this).closest('td').next('td').text();
    if (strVal=='Text 2')
        this.checked = true;
    //alert(strVal);
  });
});
```

Comment: why you dont use label?

Comment: I wasn't in control of the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.filter()` method is so concise and straight-forward:

```js
$(function(){
    $(':checkbox').filter(function(){
   return $(this).closest('tr').find('td').last().text() == 'Text 2';
    })
    .prop('checked',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Text 1</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Text 2</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Text 3</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Text 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

using javascript you can do it in different ways. I have written different sample please check it. It works event if your html structure changed

```js
$(function(){
 $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
   //this.checked = true;
    var strVal = $(this).attr("data-checkbox-text");
    if (strVal=='Text 1')
     this.checked = true;
    //alert(strVal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"  data-checkbox-text="Text 1"></td><td>Text 1</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"  data-checkbox-text="Text 2"></td><td>Text 2</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" data-checkbox-text="Text 3"></td><td>Text 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't have the option to add/change attributes of the table

Comment: then what you have written is fine. Is there a purpose that you want to do it in different way. If so then let me know the purpose

Comment: Just wanted to make sure I had to most direct route given the situation. Thanks.

Comment: Should maybe have posted this to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one too:

```
$(':checkbox').filter(function(){
    return $(this).parent().next('td').text() === 'Text 2';
}).prop('checked', true);
```